# Select text within span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

What would be an approach to select text within span tag when considering browser compatibility? Example, I have:

```
jQuery().html('<p>Hello world <span>lorem ipsum</span> my good friend!');
```

I want the `lorem ipsum` part to be *cursor* selected.

I have this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/987376/1185126) which selects text:

```
function SelectText(element) {
    var doc = document
        , text = doc.getElementById(element)
        , range, selection
    ;    
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        selection = window.getSelection();        
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice question. I would like to see an approach which works on mobile browsers too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting text in an element (akin to highlighting with your mouse)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse)

Comment: are you talking about `cursor:pointer` in css?

Comment: No. Just want lorem ipsum to be selected as if the user manually selected it with their cursor.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Wait so do you want to highlight the text with a particular background colour? Like when you copy text  on your computer?

Comment: @Henrik Petterson my answer Can Help you For Cursor Selection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select the text of a span on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451353/how-to-select-the-text-of-a-span-on-click)

Answer (score 2):

you mean like this?

```js
 var i = 0; 
function SelectText(element) {
    var doc = document
        , text = doc.querySelectorAll(element)
        , range, selection
    ;
 
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text[i]);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        selection = window.getSelection();        
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text[i]);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
  i++;
   if ( i === text.length ) i = 0;
}

document.onclick = function(e) {    
    if (e.target.className === 'click') {
        SelectText('span');
    }
};
```

```html
<div>Hello world <span>lorem ipsum</span> my good friend!</div>
<div>Hello world <span>lorem ipsum</span> my good friend!</div>
<p class="click">Click me!</p>
```

if you just need to select one tag element you can use querySelector instead of querySelectorAll

---

here's an example with .html()

```js
$(function() {
   $('body').html('<p>Hello world <span>lorem ipsum</span> my good friend!');
  })

function SelectText(element) {
    var doc = document
        , text = doc.querySelector(element)
        , range, selection
    ;
 
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        selection = window.getSelection();        
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
  
}

window.onload = function() {    
 
        SelectText('span');
    
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I mean, however, I want to output the text using .html() and have the text wrapped in <span> selected on pageload, not on click.

Comment: Thank you for the update, although the .html() is added via ajax (after pageload). Sorry I did not clarify this properly. Can you adjust your code to output .html() via ajax and have text within span tag selected? I will bounty this with 50 points when eligible for the effort. Thanks! It's been a headache all day.

Comment: the point is to call the function right after the content has been added, if you have problems open up a new question

Comment: ...lorem ipsum my old friend. I've come to talk with you again. Because a vision softly creeping hello world while I was sleeping...

Answer (score 0):

**HTML CODE**

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" value="Enter your name..." />
```

**JS CODE**

```
//SELECT TEXT RANGE
$.fn.selectRange = function(start, end) {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (this.setSelectionRange) {
            this.focus();
            this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        } else if (this.createTextRange) {
            var range = this.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', end);
            range.moveStart('character', start);
            range.select();
        }
    });
};
$('input[name=firstName]').focus().selectRange(5,10);
```

[Click Here For Permanent link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yMUx5/)

```js
//SELECT TEXT RANGE
$.fn.selectRange = function(start, end) {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (this.setSelectionRange) {
            this.focus();
            this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        } else if (this.createTextRange) {
            var range = this.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', end);
            range.moveStart('character', start);
            range.select();
        }
    });
};
$('input[name=firstName]').focus().selectRange(5,10);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="firstName" value="Enter your name..." />
```

Comment: @Henrik Petterson This Can Help you For Cursor Selection

Comment: [`setSelectionRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) is valid only in an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element, while OP referes to a `<span>`.